# Visual Foxpro : Providing command line facilities within an .exe file

Tags: command-line-interface, visual-foxpro

I distribute a fairly large application as an .exe file, App55.exe, with the appropriate .dll files.  I would like to provide the administrator of the system (presently me) with the facility to execute command line instructions, such as VALIDATE DATABASE, or to open one of the tables exclusively and re-index, ideally within this application.
Is this possible  - without including code to specifically open all the tables &c.  Does anyone perhaps have a utility which does the job.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I do have it as a utility but that utility also have some code that I don't want to disclose :( I can't just give the project for that reason, however it is fairly simple what you should do:

Create a project with a form in which you have an Editbox and a commandbutton. Editbox (say edtCode) is where you would write the code. When you click the button, your code would be compiled and run. Here is the click code:

```
Local lcCode, lcTemp
lcCODE = thisform.edtCode.Value
lcTemp = FORCEPATH(SYS(2015)+'.prg',SYS(2023))
STRTOFILE(m.lcSQL,m.lctemp)
COMPILE (m.lcTemp)
* on error do myErrHandler with ...
DO (m.lcTemp)
* on error
Erase (m.lcTemp)
```

PS: This would work with VFP6 SP3 and later versions.

Comment: Thank you Cetin.  I have tried something similar to this (omitting the reference to lcSQL), and it does the business.  Would I be right in thinking that the COMPILE instruction is there to pick up errors, so that the program does not get part-way through and then fail :  that is, would the program work without the COMPILE instruction, provided there were  no errors in the code in edtcode.value?

Comment: No, you need the COMPILE command and that is what makes it work. VFP is not a typed language that compiling would catch the errors in the sense you mean (do command does an implicit compile but do that separately).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to include on my program menu:
CodeBlock is a runtime FoxPro interpreter. It allows you to execute blocks of uncompiled code that resides in memo fields, files, or character strings, even in the runtime environment.

http://www.cycla.com/software/codeblock.htm

Comment: Thanks Eddie.  I have looked at your site and see the general idea.  In fact the download of CodeBlck.prg under Internet Explorer results in a 404 error on my machine;  but I imagine that it does something similar to Cetin's code.

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar where we create a fake Command window (an EditBox), and do the processing in the KeyPress method when Enter is pressed.  If a patch of text is selected, we execute it; otherwise, execute the last line typed.  We use EXECSCRIPT() to do the actual execution.  There's a bit more to the logic (for example, the handling of the Enter key when not on the 'last' line, etc.), but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks LAK.  I have tried EXECSCRIPT() and it works.  If I just wish to execute the instruction, I believe that ExecScript saves writing to a temporary file.  But am I right in thinking that the advantage of Cetin's approach is that it allows trapping of (some) errors without actually executing the script.

Comment: It might catch syntax errors when VFP attempts to compile/run the temporary file.  In our case, we just trap the error (with TRY...CATCH) and display the error information.